# How to filter logcat output in ACRA?

Tags: android, logcat

I am using ACRA library in my application. My debug messages write into logcat with methods from Log class. And just this messages contains 90% important information. Logcat output is included in my report. When I run it on emulator it contains only my messages and output from printStackTrace() method (as I want). But when I run it on real device (SGS4) I get too many unnecessary messages. For example:

```
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgressDrawable mProgressDrawable = null, d = android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@4257df18needUpdate = false
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgress = 0
D/ProgressBar(10716): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
D/ProgressBar(10716): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
D/ProgressBar(10716): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 228
I/endeffect(10716): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=750, getHeight()=1689, this=android.widget.ListView{427234a0 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-750,1689 #7f070083 app:id/menu_list}
I/endeffect(10716): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=750, getHeight()=1689, this=android.widget.ListView{427234a0 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-750,1689 #7f070083 app:id/menu_list}
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(10716): Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/AbsListView(10716): Get MotionRecognitionManager
W/Resources(10716): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3c a=-1}
W/Resources(10716): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3c a=-1}
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): newFrequencyRequest  - mFrequency = 800000, mTimeoutMs = -1, mPkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): Boost Request from package = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5 frequency : 800000type = 6
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): !! pkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): Request from package name pkgName = LIST_SCROLL_BOOSTER@5
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): mToken is Null....Creating New Binder!
I/CustomFrequencyManager(10716): CPUDVFSControlRequest : doFrequencyRequest::  = 800000 Timeout : -1
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(10716): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Logcat is clogged with this messages about 90%. But I not needed in this messages. How filter it correctly?

Now I am using this:

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "300", "ru.bartwell.myapp:V" }
```

Also I know that I can write my own log with my messages only and then include it to ACRA report. But is this correct to make writing into file so often? I'm afraid that is adversely affect on SD-card.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this link:

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage

```
For example, if you prefer using:
```

adb logcat -t 100 -v long ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S
then add this to you {@ReportsCrashes} config:
  logcatArguments = { "-t", "100", "-v", "long", "ActivityManager:I", "MyApp:D", "*:S" }

try to provide more specific into logcatArguments command.

writing into the sdcard so often is not the correct option.

Answer (score 1):

I get needed with it:

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "300", "MyAppTag:V", "System.err:V", "AndroidRuntime:V", "*:S" }
```